# Mouse not moving, but still clicks!

Tags: 12.04, mouse, touchpad

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Last night when I started my computer, I saw a strange screen telling me this:
The system is running in low-graphics mode
Your screen, graphics cards, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.

There, my mouse was not working and I couldn't hit the ok button!
I searched and re-installed my graphic. I fixed it and the next time it booted normal, but with the mouse not moving problem remaining! Everythings fine, but my touchpad's not moving, but it can click!
a few moments ago, when I was trying to do something, I saw this strange message: Can't grab your mouse.

And for the record, here's the last lines of my /vat/log/Xorg.0.log file:

```
[   519.404] SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: not enough space for touch events (max 1 touchpoints). Dropping this event.
[   519.404] [dix] SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: unable to begin touch point 1
[   519.434] [dix] SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: unable to find touch point 1
[   519.448] [dix] SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: unable to find touch point 1
[   519.464] [dix] SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: unable to find touch point 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the Synaptics Touchpad drivers:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

These commands will remove the Synaptics driver (and all configs) from your system, and then reinstall a clean/fresh version.